# How to solve $y(x) y'(x) +C_1y(x)^2+C_2y(x)={1\over2}C_3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y(x) y'(x) +C_1y(x)^2+C_2y(x)={1\over2}C_3
$$

C1, C2 , C3 are constants.

how to solve this equation??

Comment: It's a separable-variable DE

Comment: thank you thank you , what is a separable variable DE??

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

With suitable constant substitutions, you can rewrite as $$\frac{yy'}{y^2+2ay+b}=c.$$

Then completing the square

$$\frac{yy'}{y^2+2ay+b}=\frac{yy'}{(y+a)^2+b-a^2}=\frac{(y+a)-a}{(y+a)^2+d}y'.$$

This will integrate as the logarithm of the denominator, minus an (hyperbolic) arctangent.

$$\alpha\log((y+a)^2+d)-\beta\arctan\left(\frac{y+a}{\sqrt d}\right)=cx+C.$$

Unfortunately, you can't invert this relation.

Comment: thank you thank you. but I didn't understand completely why this equation can't invert.

Comment: @서재덕: feel free to try...